# Indexing a list when naming in a Python forloop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, format

How do I set the title of each graph to be 'firm'_price for each firm in the list?

```
firm = ["A", "B", "C"]

for i in range(len(firm)):
    ...
    firm[i].plot(title = "{0}_price".format(firm[i]), ax=ax[0])
```

Comment: You need to add more information here. What is ```company```? What is ```plot```? It looks like you are trying to call ```plot``` on a string object, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks; I've amended the post. there's some code in between. The graphs work its just the "title =" that messes up. Currently I can only get it to show "company1_price" or some variant as the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the problem is that you are changing the definition of `firm` inside the for loop, which is not advised.

I'm guessing you might be looking for something like this:

```py
firms = ["A", "B", "C"]

for firm in firms:
    some_plot_var = ...
    some_plot_var.plot(title = "{f}_price".format(f=firm), ax=ax[0])
```

That should result in titles of "A_price", "B_Price", "C_Price".

Answer (score 0):

Simple but not necessarily cheekiest answer.

```
        for i in range(len(firm)): 
            ... 
            name = str(firm[i] + "_price") 
            plot(title = name, ...)
```

Comment: UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')